# Pass state value to component

Tags: reactjs, list, material-ui, listitem

I am really new in React.js. I wanna pass a state (that i set from api data before) to a component so value of selectable list can dynamically fill from my api data. Here is my code for fetching data :

```
getListSiswa(){
  fetch('http://localhost/assessment-app/adminpg/api/v1/Siswa/')
  .then(posts => {
    return posts.json();
  }).then(data => {
    let item = data.posts.map((itm) => {
      return(
        <div key={itm.siswa_id}>
          <ListItem
            value={itm.siswa_id}
            primaryText={itm.nama}
          />
        </div>
      )
    });

  this.setState({item: item});
  });
}
```

From that code, i set a state called item. And i want to pass this state to a component. Here is my code :

```
const ListSiswa = () => (
  <SelectableList>
    <Subheader>Daftar Siswa</Subheader>
      {this.state.item}
  </SelectableList>
);
```

But i get an error that say

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'item' of undefined

I am sorry for my bad explanation. But if you get my point, i am really looking forward for your solution.

Here is my full code for additional info :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {List, ListItem, makeSelectable} from 'material-ui/List';
import Subheader from 'material-ui/Subheader';

let SelectableList = makeSelectable(List);

function wrapState(ComposedComponent) {
  return class SelectableList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    };

    getListSiswa(){
      fetch('http://localhost/assessment-app/adminpg/api/v1/Siswa/')
      .then(posts => {
        return posts.json();
      }).then(data => {
        let item = data.posts.map((itm) => {
          return(
            <div key={itm.siswa_id}>
              <ListItem
                value={itm.siswa_id}
                primaryText={itm.nama}
              />
            </div>
          )
        });

      this.setState({item: item});
      });
    }

    componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: this.props.defaultValue,
      });

      this.getListSiswa();
    }

    handleRequestChange = (event, index) => {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: index,
      });
    };

    render() {
      console.log(this.state.item);
      return (
        <ComposedComponent
          value={this.state.selectedIndex}
          onChange={this.handleRequestChange}
        >
          {this.props.children}
        </ComposedComponent>
      );
    }
  };
}

SelectableList = wrapState(SelectableList);

const ListSiswa = () => (
  <SelectableList>
    <Subheader>Daftar Siswa</Subheader>
    {this.state.item}
  </SelectableList>
);

export default ListSiswa;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is by having the **state defined in the parent component** instead and **pass it down to the child via props**:

```
let SelectableList = makeSelectable(List);

function wrapState(ComposedComponent) {
  return class SelectableList extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
      children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
    };

    componentWillMount() {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: this.props.defaultValue,
      });

      this.props.fetchItem();
    }

    handleRequestChange = (event, index) => {
      this.setState({
        selectedIndex: index,
      });
    };

    render() {
      console.log(this.state.item);
      return (
        <ComposedComponent
          value={this.state.selectedIndex}
          onChange={this.handleRequestChange}
        >
          {this.props.children}
          {this.props.item}
        </ComposedComponent>
      );
    }
  };
}

SelectableList = wrapState(SelectableList);

class ListSiswa extends Component {
  state = {
    item: {}
  }

  getListSiswa(){
    fetch('http://localhost/assessment-app/adminpg/api/v1/Siswa/')
    .then(posts => {
      return posts.json();
    }).then(data => {
      let item = data.posts.map((itm) => {
        return(
          <div key={itm.siswa_id}>
            <ListItem
              value={itm.siswa_id}
              primaryText={itm.nama}
            />
          </div>
        )
      });

    this.setState({item: item});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SelectableList item={this.state.item} fetchItem={this.getListSiswa}>
        <Subheader>Daftar Siswa</Subheader>
      </SelectableList>
    );
  }
}

export default ListSiswa;
```

Notice that in `wrapState` now I'm accessing the state using `this.props.item` and `this.props.fetchItem`. This practice is also known as prop drilling in React and it will be an issue once your app scales and multiple nested components. For scaling up you might want to consider using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction) or the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your information. This is really help for me, but when i try that code, i got another error :

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): _this3.setState is not a function

For this part :

this.setState({item: item});

I really have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Got it. i just need to add bind when i am calling the function like this : this.getListSiswa.bind(this)

Comment: glad that you made it work! alternatively you could define in arrow function `getListSiswa = () => { ... }` That way you don't need to do `bind` anymore

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this component.

```
const ListSiswa = () => (
  <SelectableList>
    <Subheader>Daftar Siswa</Subheader>
    {this.state.item}
  </SelectableList>
);
```

This component is referred as Stateless Functional Components ([Read](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html))

It is simply a pure function which receives some data and returns the jsx.

you do not have the access `this` here.